# Obtain full V matrix from Eigen SVD function

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm using the eigen library to calculate the fundamental matrix from two cameras using the 8 point algorithm. The 8 point algorithm needs the last column of the V matrix.

Comparing the results to matlab I discovered that Eigen's SVD function does not return an 8x9 V matrix (n-by-p) as matlab does but instead an 8x8 one where the 2 last columns have different values.

The Eigen documentation says "You can ask for only thin U or V to be computed, meaning the following. In case of a rectangular n-by-p matrix, letting m be the smaller value among n and p, there are only m singular vectors; the remaining columns of U and V do not correspond to actual singular vectors. Asking for thin U or V means asking for only their m first columns to be formed. So U is then a n-by-m matrix, and V is then a p-by-m matrix."

Does anyone know how to get the missing column from Eigen?

Comment: What is the size of the matrix whose SVD you want? If you know it a priori, what is the rank of your matrix whose SVD you want?

Comment: the input is an 8x9 matrix

Comment: In my experience generally either $U$ is $m \times m$, $\Sigma$ is $m \times n$, and $V$ is $n \times n$, or else $U$ is $m \times r$, $\Sigma$ is $r \times r$, and $V^T$ is $r \times n$. The former is called a full SVD, the latter is called a reduced SVD. In the reduced case $r$ is basically the rank (though because the rank is in general hard to estimate, it can be simpler to treat $r=\min \{ m,n \}$). Your objective seems very strange to me, because it is impossible for your $V$ to have orthogonal columns if it has more columns than rows.

Comment: You are right that it was computing the reduced SVD, if I tell Eigen to give me the full SVD it does generate a 9x9 for V. However the values in the last few columns are still different from those given by matlab

Comment: The SVD is very non-unique. The singular values are unique, but you can play all kinds of games with the singular vectors and still have an SVD.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure where that leaves me. There can't be multiple fudamental matrices.

Comment: Can you provide a characterization of the fundamental matrix?

Comment: The  matlab code to generate the fundamental (where {x,y,1} and {xp,yp,1} are the two sets of data points) is...      A = [ xp.*x xp.*y xp yp.*x yp.*y yp x y ones(8,1)];       
[U,D,V] = svd(A,0);      
f = V(:,end);  
F = reshape( f,[3 3])';

Comment: Can you give a characterization of where this comes from (how it relates to $A$)? In particular I do not see why you are taking the last column of your "V", which is actually a row of $V$ in the "real" SVD.

Comment: Essentially we need 8 points to obtain a unique least squares solution to the set of equations A.f = 0, where f is the fundamental and A is defined as above. This solution is the smallest singular value. [link](http://dhoiem.cs.illinois.edu/courses/vision_spring10/lectures/Lecture22%20-%20Epipolar%20Geometry.pdf)

Comment: My mistake, I forgot that MATLAB does the transposing for you in advance. OK, so it's a singular vector corresponding to the smallest singular value. *This is not unique*: the smallest singular value, $\sigma_8$, is unique, but the corresponding singular vectors satisfy the equations $Av_8=\sigma_8 u_8,A^T u_8=\sigma_8 v_i$. So even if $\sigma_8<\sigma_7$ (which can fail), there is a one dimensional subspace of such singular vectors. If you specify that you want one of a particular magnitude, then there are STILL two signs that are possible (many many more in the complex case).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess that's why I'm getting different the results. Still stumped on how to determine which is the correct fundamental matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the orientation of the axes for the nullspace $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)$.

Consider the matrix 
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}
\right].
$$
The nullspace $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)$ is the $x-y$ plane. We have many ways to orient that space 
$$
  \mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) =
\text{span } \left\{ \,
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\ 0 \\ 0
    \end{array}
  \right], \,
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\ 1 \\ 0
    \end{array}
  \right]\, \right\} =
\text{span } \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      1 \\ 1 \\ 0
    \end{array}
  \right], \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
 \left[    \begin{array}{r}
      1 \\ -1 \\ 0
    \end{array}
  \right] \,
\right\}.
$$
In fact, the general cases include reflections and rotations like
$$
  \mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) =
\text{span } \left\{ \,
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \\ 0
    \end{array}
  \right], \,
  \left[
    \begin{array}{r}
      -\sin \theta \\ \cos \theta \\ 0\phantom{-}
    \end{array}
  \right]\, \right\}, \quad
0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi.
$$